# Warning in android xml file

Tags: android, components, warnings

when I add any element in android layout, compiler(eclipse) shows a warning on element's attribute `android:text="Text"`
What does mean of following warning.

> "[118N]Hardcoded string "Text", should use @string resource"

when we add @ with string like "myString%" it gives error.

Answer (score 3):

The warning is a Lint Warning. Its warns about possible bugs. You can ignore it if you want to. But i feel its a useful info.

Instead of hardcoding string values to textview define strings in strings.xml and refer the same like @strings/mystring

Quoting from

http://tools.android.com/tips/lint

Android Lint is a new tool introduced in ADT 16 (and Tools 16) which scans Android project sources for potential bugs. It is available both as a command line tool, as well as integrated with Eclipse (described below), and IntelliJ (details). The architecture is deliberately IDE independent so it will hopefully be integrated with other IDEs, with other build tools and with continuous integration systems as well.

Here's a list of Lint Checks

http://tools.android.com/tips/lint-checks

To solve

Define the resource in res/values/strings.xml

```
  <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
```

And in xml

```
  android:text="@string/hello_world"
```

Comment: but when we add @ with string like "%myString" it gives error.

Comment: @LASIAF i din't understand. warnings are different from errors.

Comment: but when we add @ with string like "%myString" it gives error. then warning converts into an error

Comment: @LASIAF that's an error. your string resource is referred by `@string/stringname`. ALso this does not give error  `android:text="@%string/hello_world"` it will be a string.

Comment: @LASIAF if you use `%string/hello_world` again lint will warn you about it

Answer (score 3):

It means that in your res/values folder you should create a strings.xml file and inside it put a definition like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <resources> 
        <string name="my_string">Text</string>
    </resources>
```

and then use `@string/my_string` to reference it inside an xml attribute or `getResources().getString(R.string.my_string);` to use that string inside your code.

Answer (score 2):

you ll not get into a trouble. But still using `@string/yourString` in your xml ll be a good practice & it ll improve your app performance.

Nothing to worry about those warnings. Maybe the android developer thought it is not a good practice.
But if your application might support multi language one day, using @string/mystring is the best practice.

You need to declare your text in `string.xml` like :

```
  <string name="hello_world">androiddevelopmentworld!</string>
```

And you need to use in xml as text like :

```
 android:text="@string/hello_world"
```

Answer (score 1):

since everyone above explained possibly about the warning , i think i may explain the **advantage of using string resource**.If you code like `android:text="hello world"`, let's say it's the heading of your app , and it is used multiple times in your app , suddenly your boss wants to change the name , then you might want to change every where where , you have already hardcoded,by using **string resource** you can pretty much change the same string used every where , by changing just the **value of the string**

Answer (score 0):

the warning say better use the String Resource instead of Hard Coding Text for Text Attribute on Control,
there is more than of these warning like "avoid using 'px' as units,use 'dp' instead" and so on.
it's very useful to develop a good app